# Computing the 3D coordinates on a unit sphere from a 2D point

Tags: math, graphics, geometry

I have a square bitmap of a circle and I want to compute the normals of all the pixels in that circle as if it were a sphere of radius 1:

[image]

The sphere/circle is centered in the bitmap.

What is the equation for this?

Comment: They don't tend to make equations for generating geometry out of a picture.  What you're looking for is an algorithm.  Unless, of course, you already have a way of finding what you consider the center point in that picture.  In which case, please rephrase the question.

Comment: This isn't highschool [math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) homework?

Comment: no, this is one of those brain-is-mush-on-a-weekend kind of questions where I have all the info, and likely all the math from my highschool days, but I've been staring at the problem for a couple of hours without being able to write a line of code.  Purpose: make a normals and depth map for some spherical billboards in my hobby game...

Comment: Do you want a solution for a sphere centered on the origin or on an arbitrary point (x, y, z)? First is much simpler.

Comment: @Tom Zych: the sphere is centred on the bitmap's centre.  I can cope with translation if you want to call that centre 0,0 in 2D

Comment: I think you need to know the center to find out what you're trying to find out.  Otherwise the answer is ambiguous, as you can find infinite solutions rotated/translated around the arbitrary anchor point(s).  With this particular picture, though, you can cheat by dividing the width/height by 2.  Then you can use the algorithm in my answer to generate geometry...

Comment: The centre is known.  Its X,Y in 2D is W/2,H/2 and its centre in 3D is 0,0,0 (we want normals and its a unit sphere).

Comment: Ohhhh I think I get what you're getting at.  You have image data, and you're trying to generate spherical depth data for it.  Is this accurate?  Cause my algorithm won't work for that.  You want (more-or-less) ray-sphere collision tests that give the time of collision.

Comment: Yes I want to make a normals map and a depth map for a sphere.  The first step is the normals map; its a unit sphere, so the normal is just the (front facing) 3D coordinates of each pixel.  The depth, once I know the x,y,z of each pixel, is easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know much about how people program 3D stuff, so I'll just give the pure math and hope it's useful.

Sphere of radius 1, centered on origin, is the set of points satisfying:

> x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> + z<sup>2</sup> = 1

We want the 3D coordinates of a point on the sphere where x and y are known. So, just solve for z:

> z = ±sqrt(1 - x<sup>2</sup> - y<sup>2</sup>).

Now, let us consider a unit vector pointing outward from the sphere. It's a unit sphere, so we can just use the vector from the origin to (x, y, z), which is, of course, <x, y, z>.

Now we want the equation of a plane tangent to the sphere at (x, y, z), but this will be using its own x, y, and z variables, so instead I'll make it tangent to the sphere at (x<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>0</sub>, z<sub>0</sub>). This is simply:

> x<sub>0</sub>x + y<sub>0</sub>y + z<sub>0</sub>z = 1

Hope this helps.

---

(OP):

you mean something like:

```
const int R = 31, SZ = power_of_two(R*2);
std::vector<vec4_t> p;
for(int y=0; y<SZ; y++) {
    for(int x=0; x<SZ; x++) {
        const float rx = (float)(x-R)/R, ry = (float)(y-R)/R;
        if(rx*rx+ry*ry > 1) { // outside sphere
            p.push_back(vec4_t(0,0,0,0));
        } else {
            vec3_t normal(rx,sqrt(1.-rx*rx-ry*ry),ry);
            p.push_back(vec4_t(normal,1));
        }
    }
}
```

It does make a nice spherical shading-like shading if I treat the normals as colours and blit it; is it right?

---

(TZ)

Sorry, I'm not familiar with those aspects of C++. Haven't used the language very much, nor recently.

Comment: +1: Great answer. Why do you introduce the plane at the end though?

Comment: Wasn't sure if it would be needed or not, and it was easy to derive. The first and last time I messed around with this sort of program was back in the 90s and I have no idea what the usual practice is.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is often used for "fake-envmapping" effect.

```
double x = 2.0 * pixel_x / bitmap_size - 1.0;
double y = 2.0 * pixel_y / bitmap_size - 1.0;
double r2 = x*x + y*y;
if (r2 < 1)
{
    // Inside the circle
    double z = sqrt(1 - r2);
    .. here the normal is (x, y, z) ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you're limited to assuming all the points are on one half of the sphere or similar, because of the missing dimension. Past that, it's pretty simple.

The middle of the circle has a normal facing precisely in or out, perpendicular to the plane the circle is drawn on.

Each point on the edge of the circle is facing away from the middle, and thus you can calculate the normal for that.

For any point between the middle and the edge, you use the distance from the middle, and some simple trig (which eludes me at the moment). A lerp is roughly accurate at some points, but not quite what you need, since it's a curve. Simple curve though, and you know the beginning and end values, so figuring them out should only take a simple equation.

Comment: "(which eludes me at the moment)" yeap been eluding me too :)

Comment: It's the same math to find the vector from a position and angle, used in every first-person camera implementation ever. It's sin and cos, `X * sin(a) + Y * cos(A)`, I think?

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you're trying to do: generate a grid of depth data for an image.  Sort of like ray-tracing a sphere.

In that case, you want a Ray-Sphere Intersection test:

http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rtinter1.htm

Your rays will be simple perpendicular rays, based off your U/V coordinates (times two, since your sphere has a diameter of 2).  This will give you the front-facing points on the sphere.

From there, calculate normals as below (`point - origin`, the radius is already 1 unit).

**Ripped off from the link above:**

You have to combine two equations:

- Ray: R(t) = R0 + t * Rd , t > 0 with R0 = [X0, Y0, Z0] and Rd = [Xd, Yd, Zd]
- Sphere: S = the set of points[xs, ys, zs], where (xs - xc)2 + (ys - yc)2 + (zs - zc)2 = Sr2

To do this, calculate your ray (x * pixel / width, y * pixel / width, z: 1), then:

- A = Xd^2 + Yd^2 + Zd^2
- B = 2 * (Xd * (X0 - Xc) + Yd * (Y0 - Yc) + Zd * (Z0 - Zc))
- C = (X0 - Xc)^2 + (Y0 - Yc)^2 + (Z0 - Zc)^2 - Sr^2

Plug into quadratic equation:

- t0, t1 = (- B + (B^2 - 4*C)^1/2) / 2

Check discriminant (B^2 - 4*C), and if real root, the intersection is:

- Ri = [xi, yi, zi] = [x0 + xd * ti ,  y0 + yd * ti,  z0 + zd * ti]

And the surface normal is:

- SN = [(xi - xc)/Sr,   (yi - yc)/Sr,   (zi - zc)/Sr]

**Boiling it all down:**

So, since we're talking unit values, and rays that point straight at `Z` (no x or y component), we can boil down these equations greatly:

Ray:

- X0 = 2 * pixelX / width
  Y0 = 2 * pixelY / height
  <strike>Z0 = 0</strike>
- Xd = 0
  Yd = 0
  Zd = 1

Sphere:

- <strike>Xc = 1

  Yc = 1

  Zc = 1</strike>

Factors:

- <strike>A = 1 (unit ray)</strike>
- B
  = 2 * (0 + 0 + (0 - 1))
  = -2 (no x/y component)
- C
  = (X0 - 1) ^ 2 + (Y0 - 1) ^ 2 + (0 - 1) ^ 2 - 1
  = (X0 - 1) ^ 2 + (Y0 - 1) ^ 2
- Discriminant
  = (-2) ^ 2 - 4 * 1 * C
  = 4 - 4 * C

From here:

```
If discriminant < 0:
  Z = ?, Normal = ?
Else:
  t = (2 + (discriminant) ^ 1 / 2) / 2
If t < 0 (hopefully never or always the case)
  t = -t
```

Then:

- Z: t
- Nx: Xi - 1
  Ny: Yi - 1
  Nz: t - 1

**Boiled farther still:**

Intuitively it looks like C (`X^2 + Y^2`) and the square-root are the most prominent figures here.  If I had a better recollection of my math (in particular, transformations on exponents of sums), then I'd bet I could derive this down to what Tom Zych gave you.  Since I can't, I'll just leave it as above.

Comment: BTW I don't claim any efficiency here ;)  There's probably a much faster way to calculate this (simple trigonometry, like combinations of sin(x), cos(y), and vice-versa seem to be in order here).